# modify the url which accesses my api

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I've just finished creating my first api for a local project but I've come across another clause.

Currently my api can be accessed such as `/api/{StartDate}/{EndDate}`

So it can be navigated such as `www.site.com/details/201001010000/201601010000`

However, now I need it to be `/api/details?StartDate={startDate}&EndDate={endDate}`

Currently my code is this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{StartDate}/{EndDate}",
    defaults: new { StartDate = RouteParameter.Optional, EndDate = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

[HttpGet]
[Route("")]
[Route("{StartDate}/{EndDate}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(Detail))]
public IHttpActionResult GetDetail(string StartDate, string EndDate)
{
    DateTime StartDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(StartDate, "yyyyMMddhhmm", null);
    DateTime EndDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(EndDate, "yyyyMMddhhmm", null);

    IEnumerable<ConvertedDetails> detail = db.Details.Where(a => a.callDate >= StartDateTime && a.callDate <= EndDateTime).RestOfLongQuery;

    if (detail.Any())
    {
        return Ok(ResponseTrue);
    }
    return Ok(ResponseFalse);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in how you map the HTTP attribute routes and the Route attribute on your action. You can fix this by using the default http routes, which will prevent `StartDate` and `EndDate` from being part of the URL instead of parameters:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

You also don't need the Route attribute on the controller, therefore it can look like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[ResponseType(typeof(Detail))]
public IHttpActionResult GetDetail(string StartDate, string EndDate)
{
    DateTime StartDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(StartDate, "yyyyMMddhhmm", null);
    DateTime EndDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(EndDate, "yyyyMMddhhmm", null);

    IEnumerable<ConvertedDetails> detail = db.Details.Where(a => a.callDate >= StartDateTime && a.callDate <= EndDateTime).RestOfLongQuery;

    if (detail.Any())
    {
        return Ok(ResponseTrue);
    }
    return Ok(ResponseFalse);
}
```

This will make it possible for you to use the following URL to access the action:
`www.site.com/api/details?StartDate=201001010000&EndDate=201601010000`